# Numpy Array - what happens when we put 3 elements in 1st array, and 4 elements in 2nd array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I created a 2D numpy array with irregular elements in each row. Here is my code:

Input:

```
a5 = np.array([[2,4,5,8],
              [10,11,12]])

a5
```

Output:

```
array([list([2, 4, 5, 8]), list([10, 11, 12])], dtype=object)
```

Size Input:

```
a5.size:
```

Size Output:

```
2
```

Now, we can clearly see. The array has 7 elements in total. Whereas, the size output is displaying "2". Also, the output upon displaying the array is displaying something weird. Why is that?

**My Expectation:**

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  4,  5,  8],
       [10, 11, 12, 13]])
```

Size Output:

```
8
```

Comment: There are two lists (elements) in the array so this is unsurprising. Can you explain what you mean by "something weird"? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @ggorlen weird means, it should not be displaying what is in the "output" section above in my question. I wasn't expecting that.

Comment: Why not? You made a `np.array` with two regular Python lists in it, so the datatype is object and you can see the stringified form of the two lists. The expected output helps, but where did you expect the 13 to come from? `np.reshape([2,4,5,8,10,11,12,13], (2,4))` seems like what you want?

Comment: @ggorlen I have updated my question and have added "My Expectation"

Comment: In your expectation, where does the `13` come from?

Comment: @hpaulj because, I rectified the array elements so that they all are equal in size.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't do that sort of rectification for you!

Comment: I rectified it myself just to give you an example of my expectation. For instance, what I want to know is, why Numpy is giving me the result of my expectation? I mean at its core, what is it actually considering this array as? as a list?